# How to write Tests in Godot engine

Tags: testing, godot

Soo I'm developing a game with the Godot engine and I want to create some test for the code to be sure that everything is working, I can't test the game with simple actions it takes 5-10 minutes. Is there a way to write tests ???

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at [GUT](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut), the Godot unit test framework, or [WAT](https://github.com/CodeDarigan/WAT).

Differences between the two, [quoting WAT's author](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/dk6tj1/wat_40_now_with_docs/f4bx3eh/):

> - GUT runs in a scene. WAT runs in the editor itself.
> - GUT (last I checked) cannot handle creating Test Doubles that take constructor dependencies (as in it uses the _init method with
>   arguments).
> - WAT has parameterized testing (so you can do the same test multiple times only needing to define the different set of arguments per run
>   through).
> - WAT has a much larger range of asserts (I think)
> - WAT can intentionally crash a test script if one method fails (this isn't documented yet though).
> - WAT cleans up after itself with regards to memory. GUT doesn't. (Note: This was largely thanks to the recent method print_stray_nodes
>   builtin to Godot that GUT didn't have during its initial creation).
> - GUT allows for inner test classes. WAT doesn't. However WAT has the "context" attribute attached to every asserts call so you can add
>   sub-context to your describe() method context of the parent method.

Comment: There's also WAT: https://github.com/CodeDarigan/WAT I see it mentioned less, for some reason, but they both look roughly on pair. WAT integrates with the editor window (Gut didn't do it when I looked at it), Gut seems to be better to use for automated testing? Haven't really used either a lot.

Comment: @fedes. Thanks, added some info on WAT!

Comment: Just a comment to mention WAT is not godot4 compatible and doesn't seem maintained whereas GUT seems active and is godot4 compatible.

Answer (score 5):

There is also GdUnit3 https://github.com/MikeSchulze/gdUnit3 ;)

It will release in upcoming version 2.0.0 with c#-beta support.

GdUnit3 is full integrated in the Godot editor with a UI inspector to navigate over your test results.
Supports also automated testing by using the command line tool in a Github-Action

Feel free to give a try ;)

Comment: I gotta say gdUnit ended up being way more impressive than I expected.  Thanks for mentioning it!  